# Firebase App Check not working (PERMISSION DENIED) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I set up Firebase AppCheck in my Flutter App.
I added

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
```

in my main.dart code, and I added the Play Console Play Integrity SHA-256 key in Firebase AppCheck Section. And also I added

```dart
dependencies {
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.5.0')

    // Add the dependency for the App Check library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
}
```

in `build.gradle` file.

At his point, all the requests made are still invalid, even if my app is correctly published in Play Store.
[image]

Comment: Hi faccio. Did you solve this?

Comment: I had to add also SafetyNet in AppCheck on Firebase, and now it works. Even if the documentation says that it is deprecated, and we should use only Play Integrity. But Play Integrity alone doesn't work